# Limiting the PCA variables for Plotting

Tags: r, plot, pca

I am doing a PCA analysis for a dataset. I am getting 92 times the PCA on variables. I wanted to Plot it with just first two PCA coponents. PCA1 and PCA2.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Is the biplot shows only Two ? or I am little confused with the interpretations. If so, it is only for 2 component, Then how can I plot for PCA3 and PCA4.

Please find my code below.

```
  prin_comp <- prcomp(data_wide.pwy_idx, scale. = T)
  names(prin_comp)
  prin_comp$center
  prin_comp$scale
  prin_comp$rotation[1:5,1:92]
  biplot(prin_comp, scale = 0)
```

Attaching PCA components, variables and Biplot.
[image: PCA Components]
[image: PCA Plot]

Comment: These are just the first two components in your plot... So maybe you have to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are seeing only the first two Principal components notice them on the x-labels and y-labels. Suppose say you want to plot any other principal component pair you have to use the **choices** argument.

```
biplot(prin_comp, choices = 3:4,scale = 0)  
# to plot the third and fourth components
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `?biplot.princomp`...

Use `biplot(prin_comp, scale = 0, choices=c(3,4))` to plot the 3rd and 4th component.

Comment: Thanks for the help